# Releasing & maintaining modules for nodejs

Tags: git, node.js, module, package

So I've just released [my first module for nodejs](https://github.com/ketamynx/node-codein).

Things that I did:

- picked a SEO-oriented name
- posted the code on github
- added the module to [the list of modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules)
- published the module via `npm publish`

Now,

1. Do I need to do more than that, to make sure who needs it will get to my module?
2. How do I push updates with npm? I tried doing `npm publish` again, but it says I need to unpublish first, or change versions or do crazy things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to do more than that, to make sure who needs it will get to my module?

You've covered your bases as far as the basics are concerned. You may consider writing in to blog sites like [DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/) or post to some mailing lists to get the word-of-mouth out, but having your code on GitHub and your package on NPM is a solid start.

> How do I push updates with npm?

Once you've published a specific version of your module, you should not push a change to that same version--this ensures that people that expect a certain version of your module to behave a certain way can ensure that it does so. If you need to update your module, you should bump the version number in your `package.json` file and publish that.

Be sure to stick to [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) when picking version numbers, so version matchers like `~3.0.5` work. See http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#version for more details.